# How to change font-weight of div text using css?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm using a plugin in `wordpress` that creates the following `html`:

```
<div class="tmm_names">
    <span class="tmm_fname">Name</span> 
    <span class="tmm_lname">Surname</span>
</div>
<div class="tmm_job">Job title</div>
```

I need to bold the content of class "tmm_job" using `css`. I don't have the option to change  the html code so I need to make this change through `css`.

I've tried the following but it does not work:

```
.tmm_job {
   font-weight: 900;
}
```

When I tried to change the span class font-weight it worked, but for div class no. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this:

```
.tmm_job {
   font-weight: 900 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to increase font-weight simply use inline CSS

```html
<div class="tmm_job" style="font-weight: 900;">Job title</div>
```

Comment: Thank you @RaZoo. I don't have the option to change the html code. I need to do it using css only.

Comment: @zinon then use !important in your css

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code and it worked fine for me, the files themselves work perfectly. Have you checked the href link to the .css file? As long as the main.css file is in the same directory, it should work just fine.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="tmm_names">
            <span class="tmm_fname">Name</span> 
            <span class="tmm_lname">Surname</span>
        </div>
        <div class="tmm_job">Job title</div>        
    </body>
</html>
```

```
.tmm_job {
    font-weight: 900;
 }
```